# How to fix navigation toggle in mobile mode using bootstrap 4?

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I just hosting my new website, the navigation toggle works fine when i shrink the window also the toggle position is on the top right side just like what i want in my local. But after i hosted my website the navigation toogle isn't working and also the toggle position changed when i opened in my smartphone. How to fix it ?

Running Bootstrap 4.3.1, JQuery-3.4.1.min.js, JQuery-3.3.1.slim.min.js and Popper.min.js. I've no idea why this is happening after the website is hosted.

this is the screanshot of image problem :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1Jobdc7jdnJcVltR3VPeWhoV2FROU1EeDNOMWc5eFN3UVJV/view?usp=sharing

or you guys can visit this website (open it in mobile) :
http://bachtiarmuhammad.000webhostapp.com/

index.html

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Jangan Klik Bang Hihihi"></img></a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive"><!-- Showwing toogle button when become mobile layout -->
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>

   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <!-- To show navigation activated color we should have js/jquery file -->
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Beranda</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#course">Rekomendasi</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#features">Pelayanan</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#resources">Outlet</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#clients">Klien</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Kontak</a>
         </li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
<!-- End Navigation -->
```

style.css

```
/*----------- NAVIGATION ------------*/
.navbar{
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-weight: 700;
   font-size: 0.9rem; /*1rem = 60px*/
   letter-spacing: .1rem;
   background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)!important;
}
.navbar-brand img{
   /*height: 2rem;*/
   margin-top: -10px;
   margin-bottom: -10px;
   width: 20%;
   height: 20%;
}
.navbar-nav li{
   padding-right: .7rem;
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link{
   color: white;
   padding-top:  .8rem;
}
/*.active is still not working */
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover{
   color: #1EBBAE;
}
```

I expect the navigation toggle like this :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IiiJ4NaZHDksBYE7Q8W0Cnegoyjof7yR/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `width:21%` .navbar-brand class.

```
.navbar-brand {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: .3125rem;
    padding-bottom: .3125rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;

    width: 21%;   /*add this */

    line-height: inherit;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

---

Alternate solution: 
just mention the `height` and `width` of the img in px. if you want to have better UI then add `backgroud-color` and `border-radius` it nav img.

```
.navbar-brand img {
    height: 48px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    width: 48px;
    border-radius: 24px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir,  you help me to fix the toggle navigation position and also help me to improve my logo.

Comment: each of you and @lieahau have answered my question. but unfortunately i only can accept an answer, hopefully you understand sir :(

Comment: but if i just add those css properties without adding w-75 the toggle navigation won't be collapsed sir.

Answer (score -1):

as you can see here,
your `<a>` filling almost full width,
that makes the toggler has no space to place on the right screen.
[image: screenshot]

you can fix it by reducing `<a>` width.
something like this should be work.

```
<a class="navbar-brand w-75" href="#">
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Jangan Klik Bang Hihihi"></img>
</a>
```

reduce its width using `w-75`, or if it's still not enough, can use `w-50`.
it is bootstrap [sizing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/sizing/)

Comment: While you help me to fix my toggle navigation drop down menu. Thank you so much sir !